# Looking for some direction and tips toward achieving a spotlight-like shader that darkens everything else in view for AR

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, augmented-reality

Developing an AR game that is to utilize Spotlights, to add emphasis on this effect, the shader must also darken everything else in camera view.  Being in AR, I'm assuming I'd need an image effect shader to decrease the color output onto screen to simulate the lesser brightness of the area around the user; however, adding a Spotlight effect with this is becoming quite a struggle that I could really use some direction and/or tips on achieving.  Here are some examples of the end result I'm looking to achieve:

[Straight Forward and Angled Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppSKh.jpg)

This is where I'm currently at with my Shader, currently only giving one object position and will worry about multiple positions later.

```
Shader "Unlit/Spotlight"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _PointOfInterest("POI Pos", vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _CircleRadius("Spotlight size", Range(0,20)) = 3
        _RingSize("Ring Size", Range(0,5)) = 1
        _ColorTint("Room tint color", Color) = (0,0,0,0.5)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags 
        {
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
        }

        LOD 100
        // Should be on for Post Process Effects
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest Always
        Cull Off
        // -----
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma alpha : blend


            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f 
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;

                // Have to bound the value somewhere on the GPU, texcoord can go up to 7
                float3 worldPos : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            float4 _PointOfInterest;
            float _CircleRadius;
            float _RingSize;
            float4 _ColorTint;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);

                o.worldPos = mul(unity_WorldToObject, v.vertex).xyz;

                return o;

            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 darkShade = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) - _ColorTint;
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) - _ColorTint;
                float dist = distance(i.worldPos, _PointOfInterest.xyz);

                //*
                // Spotlight
                if(dist < _CircleRadius) 
                {
                    // inside the circle
                    col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                }
                // Feathering
                else if (dist > _CircleRadius && dist < _CircleRadius + _RingSize) 
                {
                    float blendStrength = dist - _CircleRadius;
                    col = lerp(tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv), darkShade, blendStrength / _RingSize);
                }
                //*/

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Not looking for direct solutions, just need direction so that I don't spend too much time chasing a destination I may be running from instead.